# Remainder using bitwise operation in Arduino sketch

Tags: c++, arduino

In Arduino sketch, can anyone help me to understand the code lines below:

```cpp
volatile unsigned int phase[] = {1000, 1000, 1000, 1000}; // an array of 2 byte int defined
    
unsigned char rem = ((unsigned char *)&( phase[0] ))[1]; // ???
```

What is the second line evaluating? I think it discards the first 8 bits and retains the last 8 bits of the 2-byte integer phase[0]. But when I replace the second line with a bitwise operation to extract the last 8 bits, then that does not go well:

```cpp
unsigned char rem  = 0b0000000011111111 & phase[0]; // extract the last 8 bits.
```

Are the second and third lines not equivalent? I need to use the bitwise operation to extract the remainder because I need to divide it by 512 instead of 256.

Thanks in advance!

P.S: Guys, the Real ISSUE is to extract the last (or lower) 9 bits of an 'int' as the remainder of a division by 512: This little-endian thing seems to further complicate.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why would you post code that doesn't even compile?  Your problem, revealed in your comments below, is solved by the simplest bitwise operations.

Comment: Now it does compile. But, 1. suggest a bitwise operation that can extract last 9 low bits from a two-byte int. 2. Secondly, explain how this line of code extracts the remainder (the last byte) not the quotient (the high byte) from the int

Comment: If you're interested in 9 bits, what's the reason for a (byte*) detour?

Comment: That was my earlier implementation when I was using a 256 size table, Now I am changing that to a 512 size table. Hope that answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
int rem = (unsigned char *)&( phase[0] )[1]; // ???
```

does not even compile

> error: invalid types 'unsigned int[int]' for array subscript

Your parenthesis are off. `phase[0]` is an unsigned integer, `[1]` preceeds `&`. So you're trying to index an unsigned integer value.

But even if you fix the parenthesis `[1]` would still give you the second byte as C++ arrays are 0-based so the lower bits are at index 0.

I'm also not sure why you store that lower byte in an integer variable.

```
unsigned char rem = ((unsigned char*)&phase[0])[0];
```

Should give you the desired `232`

You could also use a union to get those bytes conveniently.
unsigned int phase[] = {1000, 1000};

```
union S{
    unsigned int i;
    unsigned char b[2];
};

S s = {phase[0]};
```

then `s.b[0]` contains the lower byte of `phase[0]`. I find this a bit more readable than your way.

### Edit

If you're interested in the lower 9 bits of an integer why not simply use

```
int rem = phase[0] & 0x1FF;
```

You could also use the modulo operator to get the remainder of a division.

```
int rem = phase[0] % 512;
```

**If you need to use bit operations due to performance issues on an AVR I would say that you're simply using the wrong MCU. Get a faster one.**

Comment: Thanks for your efforts! I typed those lines here as a representation of an otherwise complex code and might have committed some syntax errors. ((unsigned char*)&phase[0])[1] gives 232, surprisingly!

Yes, union way is much more readable. However, I also need the code to be fast enough for the limited speed of Arduino. Also,  I wish to extract the low nine bits of an int, which is the remainder from its division by 512. 

MY REAL ISSUE: This little-endian thing further complicates it: How can I extract the last or low 9 bits of an 'int' as the remainder of a division by 512?

Comment: How can I extract the last or low 9 bits of an 'int' as the remainder of a division by 512?

Comment: @avi I can't tell if a union is really significantly slower. it will probably not matter in most applications. why not simply mask those bits? `numer =& 0x1FF;` will give you the lower 9 bits of number. you already suggested that for 8 bits in your question so I'm not sure what you're struggling with

Comment: Yes, I know the concept but still, my code is not working! that's what I am struggling with!

Comment: maybe ask a new question with more code if it is still not working

Answer (score 0):

For your understanding I added a helper variable:

```
volatile unsigned int phase[] = {1000, 1000, 1000, 1000};
unsigned char* p = (unsigned char*) phase; // reinterpret cast as an array of bytes
int rem = p[1]; // copy the second byte into another variable
```

Does that answer the first question?

Your second question assumes that the second byte of an uint16_t contains the low bits.
That's wrong for an usual Arduino. AVR controllers are LittleEndian.

```
   phase[0] is 0x3e8
   p[0] is 0xe8
   p[1] is 0x03
```

Comment: How can I extract the last or low 9 bits of an 'int' as the remainder of a division by 512?

Comment: I appreciate your reply, it's helpful. I ignored the little-endian thing. however,  MY REAL ISSUE: This little-endian thing further complicates it: How can I extract the last or low 9 bits of an 'int' as the remainder of a division by 512?

Comment: To extract the 9 low bits of an `int` is trivial and straightforward : `& 0x1FF`

Comment: Yes, it is! Thanks! We can also do that by right shifting 7 bits i.e.  INT << 7. Which of them will be faster bitwise or right shifting?